# Having difficulties with understanding some code in python

Tags: python, regex

I'm having some issues and just want to know what it may be because I've tested properly some of my code. Why is this code not working ? This is the code displayed below.

```
search_for_term = re.findall(r'<td class="kx o_\d.*data-bookmaker', doc)
```

This is the output of searc_for_term variable:

```
['<td class="kx o_1 winner" data-bookmaker',
 '<td class="kx o_0" data-bookmaker',
 '<td class="kx o_2" data-bookmaker']
```

Now I'm trying to find if any string contains word "winner". Code is shown below.

```
winner_ids = np.where([re.findall('winner', item) for item in search_for_term])
```

And now is the code which confuses me :

```
if(not all(winner_ids)):
   print("no winner")
else:
   print("winner does exist")
```

The output I get is "no winner". Can somebody explain this to me. I would be more than greatful.

Comment: What exactly do you not understand? Why did you expect to get something else as output?

Comment: Will `'*winner*'` do what you want?

Comment: Well, should it display winner does exist because winner is located in winner_ids judging by the array ?

Comment: Use `re.search()`

Comment: What if you print `winner_ids` to find out if your assumption is correct?

Comment: Please include all relevant code and data. See: [mcve]. It would be particularly useful here since some of these design choices seem odd. Also, it looks like you're using RegEx to parse HTML. I'm guessing you haven't seen [this legendary answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/11301900) yet.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Use [the beautiful soup](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/).

Then you can simply use:

```
winner = doc.find('td.winner[data-bookmaker]')
```

And the condition becomes:

```
if winner:
    print("winner exists")
else:
    print("no winner")
```

---

Reply to comment: You extract a copy of the DOM and feed to this.

You already are extracting the DOM as HTML and parsing it via RE. You might as well simply feed it to `bs4`.

Comment: I cannot use beautiful soup because website does not allow me to. I can only use selenium.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need

```
winner_ids = np.where([re.findall('.*winner.*', item) for item in search_for_term])
```

Comment: It didn't help me, but I solved the problem using is None in if conditional statement

Comment: if you post your answer it may clarify things. Thanks.